# ActionMailer automatic emails. Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Building A "Ticketing System" for our support team, so they can create tickets when a customer calls and requests something.

I have quite a lot up and running, now I need each time a ticket is created for the app to send an email to the person the the ticket is assigned to. This info is all in the DB and accessible easily.

Do you guys have any suggestion how I can imolement this or any documentation I can use?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
# Model
class Ticket

  ...
  after_create: :send_email
  ...

  def send_email
    Mailer.delay_for(5.minutes).send_ticket(id, assigned_to.id) # delay sending e-mail
    Mailer.send_ticket(id, assigned_to.id).deliver # or send it now..
  end
end

class Mailer < ActionMailer::Base

  def send_ticket(ticket_id, assigned_to_id)
    @assigned_to = User.find(assigned_to_id)
    @ticket = Ticket.find(ticket_id)
    mail(
      from: 'you<do-not-reply@your_domain.com>',
      to: @assigned_to.email,
      subject: 'new assignment'
    )
  end
end
```

this is mainly the logic, now for the views
add the following file `app/views/mailer/send_ticket.html.haml`

```
Hey #{@assigned_to.name},
%p you have been assigned to a new ticket #{@ticket.id}
%p here is the link to the ticket #{@ticket.url}
```

Comment: Thanks this is all set up now! How hard, is to take body of an incoming ticket, and make it so it creates a comment to the assigned ticket?

Comment: not that hard just a little modification in the view and you will be all set. that's why i added a this little view... please note that the `@vars` in the views must be the same as in the `send_ticket` method so that you can access them...

Answer (score 0):

Check out this Railscast to get started on your mailer - http://railscasts.com/episodes/206-action-mailer-in-rails-3

Basically, in your Ticket `create` method, you want to call the mailer and pass in the email of the assigned person so that every time a Ticket is created, it sends an email.